# MongoDB delete fields with unknown names, based on value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have something like this:

```
{
  "_id": ...,
  "section": {
    "a": "101",
    "b": "101",
    "c": "000",
    "d": "101"
  }
}
```

How can I unset all fields with value "101"? I know nothing about keys ("a", "b", "c"), only value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- schema in general must be known even if some fields are missing, so having unknown schema is not good idea
- uknown schema causes many problems and slower, more complicated queries, but you still can do it with `objectToAray` `arrayToObject` etc

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=639a2c17424f6130d7f12180)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"section": 
     {"$arrayToObject": 
       [{"$filter": 
           {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$section"},
            "cond": {"$ne": ["$$this.v", "101"]}}}]}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you think would be the most optimal solution? Your request or two requests in the form of a transaction (find, edit in code and then update)?

Comment: send this query, it will be atomic and fine, no reason for transactions, but its best to change your schema, and not save data on schema(on keys), so you know the possible key values, when you query

Comment: hmm, I'm using this as a player's inventory. it may have duplicates and I need to distinguish them somehow...

Comment: maybe try array of documents like `sections= [{type "a", value "101"} ....]`

Comment: yes, but then if server1 takes the first value from the array, server2 can try to do the same. as a result, I will get different values

Comment: updates in 1 document are always atomic, so you dont worry about 2 trying to update the document the same time, but i am not sure that i understand what you meant

Comment: my servers have a cache. and there is no guarantee that when deleting 1 element from the array, server2 will be notified. if I use an array, the first element that has already been deleted by server1 will be deleted from the database. in the case of keys, server2 will not be able to harm